# Henon maps and strange attractors

Tags: chaos-theory

What I understand of chaos is that, it cannot occur in 2D space. A strange attractor, as seen in a Lorenze system, is a feature of chaos. Now, I am reading about the Henon map which is a 2d map with a strange attractor. My question, then, is: Does a Henon map represent a chaotic system in 2D? Or is can a strange attractor occur in 2D space without the system itself being chaotic? Said another way, does chaos imply a strange attractor but a strange attractor does not imply chaos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual result is about [continuous systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem):

> A two-dimensional continuous dynamical system cannot give rise to a strange attractor

For discrete systems, such as the Henon map, you can have chaos even in one dimension, e.g. the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) is a textbook example of chaotic behavior

$$
x_{n+1} = rx_n(1 - x_n)
$$